# How to handle non-digit images in digit classifier using neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, mnist

I am experimenting with neural nets and put together a simple NN (no convolutions, just a few dense layers) to recognize handwritten digits based on **MNIST** data (see the complete code below). The network performs quite well on a test set (and on my own handwriting too). 
Experimenting with random images of **non-digits**, however, I noticed that the network becomes confused with very *high confidence*.
Namely, feeding a random noise (see below) as an image to be classified, the NN is certain it sees a specific digit.

The `model` in the code to follow represents the already trained NN and is defined and trained in the code block displayed below.

```py
    sample = (255*np.random.random(784) ).astype('uint8').reshape(( 28,28) )
    pt.imshow(sample, cmap = 'gray')
    pt.show()
    # see the result of the pt.show() below

    pred =  model.predict(sample.reshape(1, 28,28))
    print(pred)
    print('label = ', np.argmax( pred ) )

    # the result of the prediction
    # [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
    # label =  6
```

This is the image, called `sample` in the above code, on which the NN classifier predicts with absolute certainty that it is `6`.

[image: random noise]

The result does not change much if I normalize this random image according to MNIST standards (i.e. resize to 20x20 and centralize inside 28x28 box by the center of mass of the 20x20 image), the classifier is still certain it is a digit, although a different one.

My question is:

> What is the standard practice for handling the non-digit image feeds, or more generally images which are outside the predefined class (be it digits from 0-9 or something else) ?

Since the last layer of my **NN** is computed with `softmax` I was under the impression that the NN, on images which are outside the learned class, would produce a probability vector which is not concentrated on a single point, and so  the network is uncertain about the outcome. This however, is not always the case.

Here is the snippet I use to define the **NN model** (used above) and to train it.

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as pt

    digit_mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
    (X_data, y_data), (X_test, y_test) = digit_mnist.load_data()

    X_valid, X_train = X_data[:10000] / 255.0, X_data[10000:] / 255.0
    y_valid, y_train = y_data[:10000], y_data[10000:]

    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"] )

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), batch_size=10 )

    # this is what happens after the final, 10th epoch
    # Epoch 10/10
    # 50000/50000 [==============================] - 20s 396us/sample - loss: 0.0234 - acc: 0.9933 - val_loss: 0.1119 - val_acc: 0.9788

    # evaluating the trained model on test set
    model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

    # the result of evaluation
    # 10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 39us/sample - loss: 0.3711- acc: 0.9768
    # [0.3710505784509187, 0.9768]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to train your network with *negative samples*. Negative here means non-digit images. There are two standard approaches:

1. Extend your network so that it has classes for digits 0-9 and a special class for not-a-number images.
2. Train two networks, one for detecting if the image is a digit and the other for classifying the digit 0-9.

Which approach to use depends on your data. For good training you should have the same number of training images for each class. But if, say, 50% of your dataset is of non-digit images then approach 1 could cause your network to underperform. By always classifying the image as non-digit it would be right 50% of the time. In that case, approach 2 could be better.

Note also that completely random images aren't realistic nor fair for the network. In production, the network would be fed OCR images of things like paper forms and handwritten notes. Even if such images doesn't contain digits, they would contain other kinds of patterns that the network would be able to learn.

Perhaps also ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. It is an exchange more suited for machine learning questions than this one.

Comment: Good answer! What do you think of using adversarial "negative" examples?

Comment: thanks for your reply (+1). Approach 1 is what I had in mind initially, but then one needs to understand what a good sample of negative examples would be. Is it more randomly generated images or from regions from real documents which do not represent a digit (perhaps both) ? But, anyway, I should try and see how it works.

Comment: @BiRico Handling adversarial input is an open research problem and is way above my head. :) OPs random images could be seen as a form of adversarial input. The important thing is to have training images that are representative of the real data. Otherwise the network won't be able to learn which features separate which images of which class.